# Probability of seven coins

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Flip seven fair coins. Describe the state space for this situation. define a random variable corresponding to the number of heads that show when the coins land.  What is the probability that this random variable has value 3?

I got S={the combination of possibility for seven coins, which has 49 possibilities}, but I don't know if it is right and should I examine everyone of them?

Comment: I don't think you've gotten what you think you've gotten.

Answer (score 1):

There are $2^7=128$ possible outcomes.

There are 7-[choose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)-3 ways of getting three heads from seven coins:

$$^7C_3 = \frac{7!}{3! \times (7-3)!} = 35$$

There are 35 positive outcomes from a total of 128. The probability is then

$$\frac{35}{128} = 0.2734375$$

Answer (score 0):

The total number of possible states is $2^7$. The number of configurations where $3$ coins show head is the number of $3$ element subsets of a set with $7$ elements, that is ${ 7 \choose 3}=7\cdot 6\cdot 5/6=35$.